# How can I pass data to nested components from Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I get my data via AJAX from the Vue instance, and I need to pass that data to the components. I am now learning how Vue.js works, but I find the documentation a little fragmentary...

Here is aproximately my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>mysite</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <parent-component></parent-component>
</div>

<template id="parent-component-template">
    <div id="the-template">
        <div class="the-list">
            <span is="sector-item" v-for="item in sectors" :sector="item"></span>
        </div>
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="sector-item-template">
    <span>
        {{ sector.name }}
    </span>
</template>

<!-- Vue.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>

<script>
    Vue.component('parent-component', {
        template: '#parent-component-template'
    });

    Vue.component('sector-item', {
        props: ['sector'],
        template: '#sector-item-template'  
    });

    let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            sectors: [{
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'Industry'
            }]
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "sectors" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
```

Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: You need to pass `sectors` as a prop to your parent component

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is not complete. I tried to simulate what you trying to, in the snippet bellow:

```js
Vue.component('parent-component', {
  props: ['sectors']
});

Vue.component('child-component', {
  props: ['item']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sectors: [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Industry'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Education'
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.the-list > div {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <parent-component :sectors="sectors" inline-template>
    
    <div class="the-list">
      <child-component :item="sector" :key="sector.id" v-for="sector in sectors" inline-template>
        <div>
          <span v-text="item.name"></span>
          <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </child-component>
    </div>
    
  </parent-component>
</div>
```

The Vue instance owns the property `sectors` and I passed this property as a `prop` to the `<parent-component>`.

Now `<parent-component>` has a prop called `sectors`(it could be another name) that received the value of `sectors` from the main Vue instance. I've used `v-for` to iterate over all items of the **parent-component prop** passing each item of the array to the `<child-component>`.

The `<child-component>` has a prop called `item` in which I passed the value of each element of the array.

You can learn more, [here](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/3) *for free*.

*I hope this answer can be helpful.*

Comment: Very helpful. Many Thanks! :)